# How to formally say "I just would like to get this over with, so you and I do not have to think about it any more"

Tags: formality

I am currently in a state where my former employee does not respond to my email. I am tired of bothering them.

I do not know if my email is blocked, but I do not think it hurts to write things formally regardless.

So I have a question.

How would I say "I just would like to get this over with, so you and I do not have to think about it any more"

I came up with

"Please do not misunderstand me, but I just would like to get it over with as much as you do. I just would like to take this matter out of my plate, so you and I do not have to be bothered by it constantly at the back of my head."

How does this sound?

I am writing this in the middle of the night because I am caught up in thinking about the same matter and I am just little tired of it. If it sounds little stressed I deeply apologise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would appreciate if we could come to an agreement on this issue by the end of [latest date].

By saying "we" you're taking the onus off your former employee or employer, it's no longer *his* responsibility, inasmuch as reaching a settlement will benefit the both of you.

If you want to sound friendlier and less assertive

> I'd really like us to come to some sort of arrangement over this issue which has been troubling me greatly. When would be the best time for you?

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. I sincerely appreciate it. The latter seems to address my concern as well as describing the fact that I am having headache over the issue. I will choose it as the answer.

Comment: @publicats Good luck in the future!

Answer (score 1):

"I would like to reach closure on this issue".

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. I still do wish to express my eagerness to receive reply so I do not have to be bothered by this any further. Is there good expression for this?

Answer (score 0):

Getting something "OFF your plate" refers to completing a task (not used for a social obligation like an apology)

You could say:

"Get this monkey off my back"
"Put this behind us"
"Talk about the elephant in the room"
"Clear the air"
"Clear my conscience"
"Start over with a clean slate"

(Doesn't make sense that someone else would be bothered by something in the back of YOUR head,)

Comment: Thank you very much for many examples. However, I am not trying to apologize here. I am just thinking it is annoying for them to see me trying to remind them over and over. I certainly am tired. May be they are forgetting (may be they are blocking). I do not know. They are not responding.

Comment: Also, is it formal to use idioms that has animals in them? For some odd reason, I feel it is very informal to use idioms that contains animals. I do not know why.

Comment: Oops. (Sorry.)"Please let me know ASAP if you are unable or unwilling to address this issue, so I can make other arrangements."

Comment: Sure, animal expressions can be formal. To call someone a "preening peacock" or a "pompous ass" is the height of formality.